# DagsterImportError: Encountered ImportError: `cannot import name 'URL' from 'datasets'

Tags: dagster

I am running `dagster dev` in a folder created by running `dagster project scaffold --name dagster_pipeline`:

[image]

assets.py imports a constant from datasets.py that I have added:

```
import requests
from dagster import asset

from datasets import URL

@asset
def datasets(url: str = URL) -> str:
    return requests.get(url).text
```

**init**.py is unchanged:

```
from dagster import Definitions, load_assets_from_modules

from . import assets

all_assets = load_assets_from_modules([assets])

defs = Definitions(
    assets=all_assets,
)
```

I see the following error in the output:

```
dagster._core.errors.DagsterImportError: Encountered ImportError: `cannot import name 'URL' from 'datasets' (C:\Users\agevorgyan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\__init__.py)` while importing module dagster_pipeline. Local modules were resolved using the working directory `C:\Users\agevorgyan\IdeaProjects\{project_name}\dagster_pipeline`. If another working directory should be used, please explicitly specify the appropriate path using the `-d` or `--working-directory` for CLI based targets or the `working_directory` configuration option for workspace targets.
```

What am I doing wrong? I saw a similar error while running code copied from the tutorial, so is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Worked after I changed the syntax to `from . import datasets`.